# What is entropy of a variable described by Knightian uncertainty?

Tags: pr.probability, shannon-entropy

Given a discrete variable whose value is characterized by [Knightian uncertainty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightian_uncertainty), that is, *belief* and *plausibility*, as in [Dempster-Shafer theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster-Shafer), what is its entropy?